# Combinatorial Row-Wise multiplication of two DataFrames in Python

Tags: python, numpy, combinatorics

Suppose I have two dataframes A and B:

A and B can be represented as numpy arrays, both of shape (N,M) i.e. N rows, M columns.

What is the fastest way to combinatorially sum-product every row of A with every row of B so that we are left with a result vector C whose shape is (N*N,1)?

The stupid way to do it is with two for-loops but I'm wondering if there is a smarter facility within Python.

Comment: Convert to arrays, then `A @ B.T`

Answer (score 0):

As per @WarrenWeckesser (I was about to jump into and `np.einsum` answer before I read the much simpler method)

```
A = B = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) + 1
A

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

(A @ B.T).reshape(-1, 1)

array([[14],
       [32],
       [32],
       [77]])
```